# Next.js production - dockerized build cant find environmental variables set

Tags: docker, next.js, production-environment

I am trying to build my next.js application with production-grade options, namely Docker and `NODE_ENV=production`, and it doesnt seem to find the environmental variables I set.

Here is what I try:

- I set my enviromentals during runtime with Docker. `docker run -e "ENV1=env1" my_app`
- next.config.js has the following snippet as instructed in the docs

```
module.exports = withImages(withCSS({
  target: 'server',
  env: {
    ENV1: process.env.ENV1
```

- To start docker I use the command `RUN npm run build`
   and to run start it, the command `RUN ["npm", "run", "docker"]` which translates to `cross-env NODE_ENV=production PORT=3000 node server.js`
- If I change NODE_ENV to `NODE_ENV=development` it works fine.

So when I try to do anything that involves an environmental I get an error stating the environmental is undefined.

I believe I am missing something from the documentation, but not sure what. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any code that loads your .env file based on `NODE_ENV`?

Comment: I am not using a .env file, just passing the environmental vars during docker run. Apart from those things I am mentioning, I am not using any other libraries. Just using process.env.ENV1 whenever needed